# How to use SVN to check out a working copy, while having a progress bar of that operation in C# visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, svn, visual-studio-2015, progress-bar

I know I can run command line commands that would start and run svn checkout, but I want to be able to monitor it by creating a progress bar that would monitor the download. Is there any way that this can be accomplished?

Comment: I couldn't help notice this other question you posted. I must point out, it's too broad for Stack Overflow (this is true of pretty much any question that is phrased as "is there any way" or an equivalent). The first step is to determine whether your command line command offers any sort of mechanism for even understanding how the operation is progressing. If there is none, then the answer is simply "no, there's no way". If there is a way, then you need to work on that, and then the display of the progress bar separately.

Comment: A good question will include a good [mcve] and details of what specific difficulty you are having.